# Java String Class Methods , split & replace

Tags: java, string, replace, split

so guys i was watching a code where returns a string to int from a websites server top zone 
and and servers top zone web sites work with votes if your server has the biggest amount of votes you get the first place in the rank so what i am getting from the site is the votes that the server has as a string ( i found the script in another forum ) and try it myself to test or understand it and i don't understand one thing
in this script;

```
String tozponeURL = "http://l2topzone.com/lineage2/server-info/9974/L2Xerus.html";
        URLConnection con = new URL(tozponeURL).openConnection();
        con.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.76");
        isr = new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream());
        br = new BufferedReader(isr);

        String line;
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null )
        {
             if (line.contains("<div class=\"rank\"><div class=\"votes2\">Votes:<br>"))
                 {
                    int votes = Integer.valueOf(line.split("<div class=\"rank\"><div class=\"votes2\">Votes:<br>")[1].replace("</div></div>", ""));
                    return votes;
                 }
```

so what this [1] is in the replace method? i cant understand

please help me! i searched the documentation but can't understand

Comment: `line.split` returns an array. `[1]` accesses the second element of the array.

Comment: @AntonH that should be an answer not a comment.

Comment: @IanRoberts I know, but for small questions like that, I can't be bothered. I've missed so much rep that way ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The java split method returns a **String Array**:

```
line.split("....")
```

so:

```
line.split("....")[1]
```

is the String at index `1` of the array

Comment: so in my case the 0 one is this ? <div class=\"rank\"><div class=\"votes2\">Votes:<br> and the 1 is the next one?

Comment: No, it *splits* the line every time it sees `"<div class=\"rank\"><div class=\"votes2\">Votes:<br>"`. A stupid example would be a String `aaa<div class="rank"><div class="votes2">Votes:<br>bbb`, and `[0] = "aaa"` and `[1] = "bbb"`.

Comment: No. `split()` splits this line string around matches of the given regular expression. see documentation here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String) @Nick

Answer (score 2):

When a string is split, it creates an array holding each token. line[1] is referring to the second token in the String line and then its calling replaceAll() on that particular token.